# Attention examples that used on non-NLP area?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, seq2seq, attention-model

When I am looking for attention implementation examples, encoder-decoder structure with attention always comes to the first. Is there any examples that using attention for other area besides NLP?

Comment: will be better answered at https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think shortly after attention mechanism is introduced in Neural Machine Translation (NMT, and yes part of NLP), it was adapted to CV in this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03044.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.08264.pdf) which adapts the attention mechanism to a non-nlp area: The molecule attention transformer. Molecules are constructed like a graph, similar to a sentence. An atom has a distance to the other atoms and they are dependent to each other, like words are in a sentence. In the paper, they "adapt Transformer (Devlin et al., 2018) to  chemical  molecules  by  augmenting  the  self-attention with inter-atomic distances and molecular graph structure."

But there are probably more application fields for transformers, at least where data has a graph-like structure and nodes are somehow dependent to each other.